# Unable to use only Light or Dark theme on Nativescript

Tags: nativescript-angular, app-themes, android-darkmode

I'm developing a Nativescript (version 6.3.3) app with Angular 8.2 and @nativescript/theme 2.2.1 with scss themes. 
I'm trying to use only Dark (or only Light) theme regardless of system mode (Dark/Light) but nothing seems to work.
I followed this guide https://github.com/NativeScript/theme and I used custom color variables setting the dark ones equal to the light ones but it doesnt' work.
Can someone support me?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to force Light or Dark mode only on iOS you can add the following to your Info.plist file.

For light mode:

```
    <key>UIUserInterfaceStyle</key>    
    <string>Light</string>
```

For dark mode:

```
    <key>UIUserInterfaceStyle</key>    
    <string>Dark</string>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

For Android,
First add this code in main.ts or main.js

```
import Theme from "@nativescript/theme";
Theme.setMode(Theme.Light);
```

Then change this value in styles.xml file located in folder values-v29 from true to false

```
<item name="android:forceDarkAllowed">false</item>
```

Comment: I had everything except this "import Theme from "@nativescript/theme";
Theme.setMode(Theme.Light);" and it did not work. Nativescript is great again.

Answer (score 0):

Also {N} Theme 2.3.x have some important fixes to force the mode. Try with 2.3.2.